# Can I say "a first and second legs"?

Tags: articles, plural-forms, nouns, indefinite-article

There are a first leg and a second leg of a table.

Can I say "a first and second legs of a table"?

As far as I know, "a" can't be put with "-s" which represents  plural nouns.

Thanks.

Comment: *The first and second legs of the table.*  See here http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/grammarlogs2/grammarlogs397.htm

Answer (score 1):

The sentence should read:

> **The** first and second legs of a table

The definite [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)) must be used since you are referring to two particular legs. The article "the" is for both singular and plural nouns.

Also, you are correct in saying English has no plural indefinite article.